# UpdateProgress not showing on first postback

Tags: asp.net, webforms, user-controls, updatepanel, updateprogress

I am working on an app that loads modules (which are just user controls) into a single update panel.  UpdateMode="Always".  There is an UpdateProgress control with a gif that should display on postback.

For a few modules, the UpdateProgress doesn't show until the second postback from the module.  So for example, the one module has a dropdown that posts back on change.  If the user changes the dropdown before doing anything else, there will be no indication (no progress gif) that it is posting back.  If the user then changes the drop down again (or any other postback), the UpdateProgress shows.  Any ideas?

I've verified that it isn't just the drop down control and the initial postback takes long enough that the progress gif should show.  UpdatePanel code below, module user controls are loaded in cphMain.

I am currently working around this by doing a __doPostBack in JavaScript when the module loads, but this is ugly.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upMain" runat="Server" UpdateMode="Always">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:UpdateProgress ID="uPrgMain" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="upMain">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                <h4>
                    <asp:Image ID="imgLoading" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/loading.gif" AlternateText="Loading" />
                    Loading...</h4>
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphMain" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `AssociatedUpdatePanelID` match the UpdatePanel's `ID`? Or is that UpdateProgress supposed to show the progress of another UpdatePanel?

Comment: Yes.  I made an error in the post, but the code is as you described and still has the issue.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? I'm having the same problem. Thanks!!

Comment: I just realize my problem was related to a javascript that was hiding my div with the animation...